# Button Image via DropDown List (Designer)"

Tags: windows, forms, button, devexpress

I want to implement my own Designer-Property for a custom class which inherit of the (DevExpress.Simple-)Button.
It should work similar to the ImageIndex-Property with a preview of the image and the name instead of the index number.

My problem is, that I can't select a value of my Drop Down-Property.
I'm sure that I've to override a method in my ImgColNamesPropertyGridEditor-class but I don't know which one.

The Button:

```
public class CButton1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton
{
    private CImageCollection.Names ICNames = CImageCollection.Names.none;

    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DefaultValue(CImageCollection.Names.none)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [Editor(typeof(ImgColNamesPropertyGridEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public CImageCollection.Names ImageName //Names is an Enum
    {
        get { return ImageNameGetter(); }
        set { ImageNameSetter(value); }
    }

    private CImageCollection.Names ImageNameGetter()
    {
        CImageCollection imgCol = CImageCollection.Instanz;
        if (this.ImageList == imgCol.Imagecollection)//Only if we use our Collection
        {
            return imgCol.GetEnumFromIndex(this.ImageIndex);
        }
        return CImageCollection.Names.none;
    }

    private void ImageNameSetter(CImageCollection.Names value)
    {
        CImageCollection imgCol = CImageCollection.Instanz;
        if (this.ImageList == imgCol.Imagecollection)//Only if we use our Collection
        {
            ICNames = value;
            this.ImageIndex = imgCol.GetIndexFromEnum(value);
        }
    }

    public CButton1()
    {
        CImageCollection imgcol = CImageCollection.Instanz;
        this.ImageList = imgcol.Imagecollection;
    }
}
```

The UITypeEditor:

```
class ImgColNamesPropertyGridEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override bool GetPaintValueSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        //Set to true to implement the PaintValue method
        return true;
    }

    public override void PaintValue(PaintValueEventArgs e)
    {
        CImageCollection col = CImageCollection.Instanz;
        string _SourceName = col.GetEnumFromIndex((int)e.Value).ToString("g");

        //Draw the corresponding image
        Bitmap newImage = (Bitmap)CButtonRes.ResourceManager.GetObject(_SourceName);
        Rectangle destRect = e.Bounds;
        newImage.MakeTransparent();
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, destRect);
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem we have to override the EditValue-Method but first we have to change the GetEditStyle-Method.

```
public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }
```

Now let's override the EditValue-Method. There we have a lot of opportunitys we can use.
Example: I want to check if my Button has an ImageList.

```
public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {

        // If it is a Button an his ImageList is empty,
        // it doesn't need a Dropdown
        if (context.Instance.GetType() == typeof(CButton))
        {
            CButton button = context.Instance as CButton;
            if (button.ImageList == null)
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
```

And now we have to create our own Panel. There we can do a lot of cool Stuff. (Later more) We let drop that panel down. (editorService.DropDownControl(inep);)
After its closed, we should return the selected value. (return inep.EnumValue;)

```
        //Panel with a ImageListBox and my Enum-Items
        ImageNameEditorPanel inep = new ImageNameEditorPanel(editorService);
        inep.EnumValue = (CImageCollection.Names)value;

        editorService.DropDownControl(inep);

        return inep.EnumValue;
    }
```

To make a Panel, which looks like a DropDown List, I used a Panel and Docked (Fill) a DevExpress-Control (ImageListBoxControl) in it.
But you can do it without DexEx. There are two ways; a hard one and an easy way.
The hard one is to use an Imagelist and draw manually the image and the text.
The easy on is to use a Treeview and give it your Imagelist. Make parent nodes and set the right ImageIndex.
In the Constructor you have to set events, to close the panel, if something was clicked.
Constructor:

```
public ImageNameEditorPanel(IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.EditorService = editorService;
        this.Size = new Size(Size.Width, Size.Height + 100);
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        [...]
        imageListBoxControl1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(lbMouseUp);//Set Value
        imageListBoxControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(lbSelectedIndexChanged);//Close
        Controls.Add(imageListBoxControl1);// Don't forget that one! Took me an eternity to figure out...
    }
```

Method:

```
    void lbMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        EditorService.CloseDropDown();
    }
```

Now it's done! If you want to implement a Dialog, create a From and use ShowDialog(form) instead of DropDownControl(panel).